# Why am I getting the wrong answer using sys.stdin and sys.stdout instead of using input() and print() function?

Tags: python, stdout, stdin

```
def no_of_div(s):
    n = len(s)
    divisors = [s]
    for i in range(2,n+1):
        d = n//i
        if d*i==n and s[0:d]*i==s:
            divisors.append(s[0:d])
    return divisors
s1 = input()
s2 = input()
print(len(set(no_of_div(s1)).intersection(no_of_div(s2))))`
```

This code is working correctly but the below code is not giving the correct result. I have just changed the input and output functions.

```
from sys import stdin,stdout
inpt = lambda: stdin.readline()
prnt = lambda x: stdout.write(str(x))
def no_of_div(s):
    n = len(s)
    divisors = [s]
    for i in range(2,n+1):
        d = n//i
        if d*i==n and s[0:d]*i==s:
            divisors.append(s[0:d])
    return divisors
s1 = inpt()
s2 = inpt()
prnt(len(set(no_of_div(s1)).intersection(no_of_div(s2))))
```

Comment: What result is it giving?

Comment: @Guru72 it is always giving zero...

Comment: Can you provide an example of 2 inputs and the expected output?

Comment: The second version is going to have a newline at the end of your input strings.

Comment: @jasonharper, how can i fix that. I mean how can i take input correctly ( like input() function) using stdin?